# Java | retrieving data

Tags: java

I have made a Tower Defense game and there is one thing that bothers me. I have set the starting value of money but I cannot get the value to carry over to the next level. Any ideas?

```
    public void define() {
    room = new Room();
save = new Save();
    store = new Store();

    if(level == 1){
    coinage = 50;
    health = 100;
    }

    if(level == 2){
    coinage = 40;
    health = 100;
    }
    if(level > 2){
        coinage = 30;
        health = 100;
    }

    if(level > 8){
        coinage = 0;
    }
```

Hmm so I tried this:

```
public static int coinage = 0, health = 100;
```

and then

```
    if(level == 1){
    coinage += 50;
    }

    if(level == 2){
    coinage += 40;
    }
```

I am sure I am doing something wrong here. When the second level comes up the starting value is still 40. 
How could I fix that?

Here is [a link to the full code](http://pastebin.com/2zK4qU0h)!

Comment: Looks like there's code missing. Where are `coinage` and `health` declared? Where do you try to retrieve their values? That aside, it seems to me that you should use a chain of if-elses instead of individual if statements. It express your intentions more clearly and it's slightly more efficient. For that matter, setting the health to the same value in 3 of the branches is pretty redundant.

Comment: @Doval opps, that was for testing. I forgot to take that out.

Comment: Alright I printed out the coinage and it started at 0 and the added to 40. So I know that part is working.

Comment: It sounds like the `+= 40` is working then if it started at 0, and added to 40.  I don't see what the issue is now.  Try having like 10 leftover after the end of the first round to see if it adds 40 to get to 50 total.  If it prints out `10` then `50` but when your second level starts it still displays `40`, then something else is wrong (you aren't using the correct value in the right spot vs. not setting coinage properly).

Comment: Hmm, it is still only at 40. Would it help if you could see the whole file? Like you said I might not have it in the right spot

Comment: There @Walls I have included a link to the code or you can click on it here [link](http://pastebin.com/2zK4qU0h)

Comment: @Minecraftonian the code is kinda all over the place in a giant method.  
1. I don't see where `coinage` is used outside of setting it. 2. You have a lot of `ifs` that SHOULD be `if else` chains like the first comment.  These are causing multiple `if`s to possibly be true... and in the later ones you are again doing the old method of staticly setting coinage to a number, instead of adding.  I don't see where coinage is displayed, so how do you know it is wrong?  If you have another class that is trying to use coinage, maybe it has its own version of it having 2 variables for the same item.

Comment: @Minecraftonian you are also setting the value of `coinage` to zero in your `hasWon()` method.  This could be virtually resetting it if after every level this `hasWon()` gets called... which would be resetting coinage to zero, and then when you `define()` it is adding onto it, but adding onto the reset zero number.

Comment: Thanks so much @Walls what fixed it was taking out the part where I redefined coinage in the hasWon() method.

Comment: @Walls I apologize but I am unable to upvote due to my level being too low but I am most thankful for all of your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `coinage` is your money, you can set a global variable outside of this `define()` function.  Let that keep track of how much money the player has.  Instead of setting the value to a direct number you can instead add to the existing value.  So in you example of level 2, `coinage += 50;`.  This would take the global value of `coinage` and add 50 to the existing number, instead of setting it to a specific value.  By just using `=` you are saying it is EXACTLY X/Y.  By keeping it global, you can add/subtract onto it and manipulate it in more ways.

I think the key though by looking at the code you have, is to just switch it to use something like `+=` instead of just `=`.  This way it will be adding to the existing value, instead of just setting it to a static number each time.